# Emergency database does not shut down

Tags: postgresql

I did

```
pgsqld stop
```

and the command line was like

```
Stopping PostgreSql:
```

and I have waited for seconds, and I pressed ctrl+C to cancel it, because I just thought something is going wrong.

and I tried it again, then I saw the message like

```
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

and I checked the status

```
pgsqld status
// pg_ctl: server is running (PID: XXXXX)
```

In short, it seems the database is still running, and I cant shut down, BUT my service is dead now... please help me to shut down and start again.

++ when I tried to login to the pgsql server like

```
psql -U postgres
// FATAL: the database system is shutting down...
```

Comment: Next time, let it run. Don't run ctl-c unless its been more than 10 minutes or something... What does `ps aux | grep -i postgres' show? As Saxtheowl just mentioned, you need to identify the PID (and this is one way to help you do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is different options you can try if the database is not shutting down properly:

first identify the PID

```
pg_ctl status
```

then try to kill it with its PID

```
kill [PID]
```

then you should be able to start your database again

Comment: I was hesitating to do this, but you gave me courage. thanks bro.

Comment: My pleasure :))

Comment: As explained in [kill -9 a postgres process](https://serverfault.com/questions/415188/kill-9-a-postgres-process) it should not be used unless it doesn't react to SIGTERM.

Comment: I updated to do just kill then